# No of rows in a group

Tags: r

I have two varaibles A and B

```
a
neat
neat
sweet
sweet
```

I want to group the variable a and get the no of rows in each group. In the above case it will be 2 for each group

Comment: The `dplyr`: `df %>% group_by(a) %>% summarise(n = n())` or just `df %>% count(a)`. `table(df$a)` works too, depending on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `aggregate`

```
aggregate(df, list(df$a), length)

#   Group.1 a
#1    neat  2
#2   sweet  2
```

---

Or as mentioned in comments by @alistaire you can also use `table` to get the frequency of each unique word

```
table(df$a)

# neat sweet 
#  2     2
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'a', we assign (`:=`) a new column ('b') with the number of rows (`.N`).

```
setDT(df1)[, b := .N, by = a]
```

---

Or using `ave` from `base R`

```
df1$b <- with(df1, ave(seq_along(a), a, FUN = length))
```

Or if the 'a' column is ordered,

```
df1$b <- cumsum(!duplicated(df1$a))
```

---

If we need the summarized output instead of creating a new column

```
setDT(df1)[, .(b = .N), by = a]
#       a b
#1:  neat 2
#2: sweet 2
```

Or with `base R`, we can use `tabulate` which will be very fast.

```
tabulate(factor(df1$a))
```